# Rails/Arel: Selecting all records as an ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel, active-relation

Using Arel in Rails - I'm looking for a way of creating an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that effectively results in `SELECT * FROM table`, which I can still manipulate further.

For example, I have a model that's split up into multiple categories, and I return counts for these in the following manner:

```
relation = Model.where(:archived => false) # all non-archived records
record_counts = {
  :total => relation.count,
  :for_sale => relation.where(:for_sale => true).count
  :on_auction => relation.where(:on_auction => true).count
}
```

This works fine, and has the advantage of firing off `COUNT` queries to MySQL, rather than actually selecting the records themselves.

However, I now need to include archived records in the counts, but `relation = Model.all` results in an `Array`, and I'm looking for an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

The only way I can think of doing this is `model.where(model.arel_table[:id].not_eq(nil))`, which works, but seems slightly absurd.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Rails 4.1 and above: `Model.all` returns a relation (where it previously did not)

For Rails 4.0: `Model.where(nil)`

For Rails 3.x: `Model.scoped`

Comment: On Rails 4.0.13, `Model.all` returns a relation and `Model.scoped` is deprecated.

Answer (score 48):

Try `relation = Model.scoped`. That will give you the relation instead of the actual results.

Comment: `Model.scoped` is deprecated in Rails 4.X. See other answer.

Comment: Thanks again, I've accepted Kyle's answer now since it provides a more complete picture of different Rails versions.

Answer (score 1):

You would want:

```
relation = Model.scoped
```

which if you see what relation is, it is in fact an `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

As you can see from this page:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scoped

It says the following:

> Anonymous scopes tend to be useful
>   when procedurally generating complex
>   queries, where passing intermediate
>   values (scopes) around as first-class
>   objects is convenient.

Comment: The only time `scoped` is really necessary is when you want to act on all of the records, like `Model.all`. Just doing a `Model.where(:archived => false)` will already just return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.