# Can you get a chainable query method with all records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm writing a controller method which may optionally modify a query (eg, by ordering it).

Coming from a django background, I would normally do something like:

```
def method(**kwargs):
    data = Model.all() # in django, this is a QuerySet

    # chain the order if required
    if 'order' in kwargs:
        data = data.order_by(kwargs['order'])
```

I tried to do the same in ruby:

```
def method
  @data = Model.all # in rails, this is an *array*

  if params.has_key? :sort then
    @data = @data.order(params[:sort])
    # also do other things, which is why this isn't a one-liner
  end
```

However, `.all` returns an `Array`, so that is not possible.

I've had a look through the [Active Record Where Chain Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where), but I can't find anything which will return a chainable object representing the whole query.  Is this possible?

(The requirement I'm after is that if `:sort` is not a param, `@data` is still usable anywhere where a `WhereChain` object is expected.)

Comment: So what could `:sort` be? is it the field by which the sort will be sorted?

Comment: @TamerShlash In this case, `params[:sort]` would be the field, yes. I'm not fussed about that part, though; I'm just after a chain-able view of all objects

Comment: Can you do `@data = Model` then chain it?

Comment: I think you're looking for `@data = Model.all.sort_by &:field_name`.

Comment: Or maybe `@data = Model.order(:field_name)`.

Comment: Use `Model.scoped`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595901/rails-arel-selecting-all-records-as-an-activerecordrelation

Comment: @Baloo - will `Model` work in contexts where `Model.order` would?  (eg, is it enumerable?)

Comment: @Thahakp - thanks, that's what I was after.  Marking this as a duplicate.